# Android ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() "source not found"

Tags: android, file, inputstream

I built a sample app which gets input from user and save in a text file "sample" in  assets folder of my app.

Here is my MainActivity.java,

```
 package com.example.sampledatabaseapp;

 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 import java.io.FileOutputStream;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.res.AssetManager;
 import android.text.Editable;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.Toast;

  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

protected static final android.content.Context Context = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            EditText txtname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);    
            String name=txtname.getText().toString();

             AssetManager am=Context.getAssets();
            try {

                InputStream is=am.open("sample");
                OutputStreamWriter out=new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("sample",MODE_APPEND));
                out.write(name);

                out.close();
                Toast.makeText(Context,"Text Saved !",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(Context,"Sorry Text could't be added",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

 }
```

my activity_main.xml,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
    android:ems="10" 
    android:hint="@string/Enter_Name">

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginTop="82dp"
    android:text="@string/Save" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I started to debug line by line and when the debugger debugs the line " AssetManager am=Context.getAssets();" in my MainActivity.java file, it shows that "source not found for ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run()." I downloaded the source code and attached.

But still, I dont know where I went wrong.
   Here is my stack trace,

```
  12-27 13:32:16.467: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(1803): KeyEvent: ACTION_UP but key was not down.
  12-27 13:32:16.467: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(1803):   in  android.widget.Button{40d02568 VFED..C. .F....I. 135,168-345,216 #7f070001 app:id/button1}
  12-27 13:32:16.467: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(1803):   0: sent at  5236119000000, KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_TAB, scanCode=15, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=5236119, downTime=5235983, deviceId=0, source=0x101 }

  12-27 13:32:16.908: W/Trace(1803): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
  12-27 13:32:16.938: W/Trace(1803): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
  12-27 13:32:16.969: W/Trace(1803): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
  12-27 13:32:16.969: W/Trace(1803): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
  12-27 13:32:17.008: W/Trace(1803): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
  12-27 13:32:17.038: W/Trace(1803): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
  12-27 13:32:17.118: W/Trace(1803): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
  12-27 13:32:17.148: W/Trace(1803): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
```

I dont know if I am using the correct approach for writing text to text file in android. If it is wrong Please suggest.

please any one help!!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MODE_APPEND is of course to append data to a existing file.
If you would like to create new one, you should use MODE_PRIVATE

```
OutputStreamWriter out=new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("sample",MODE_PRIVATE));
```

And when you read the file,

```
        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream;
            fileInputStream = openFileInput("sample");
            byte[] readBytes = new byte[fileInputStream.available()];
            fileInputStream.read(readBytes);
            String readString = new String(readBytes);
            Log.v("readString", readString);
            fileInputStream.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
```

OK, How about deleting this line?

```
AssetManager am=Context.getAssets();
```

You don't have to use AssetManager.

And then you use write this.

```
try {
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = openFileOutput("myfile.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
            String writeString = "test";
            fileOutputStream.write(writeString.getBytes());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
```

Comment: Thats fine. But still the Error is being shown. After debugging assentmanager line the thread execution is being stopped by throwing an error.